# Apache HTTP 4.x: How can the "default context" be configured on HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

In Apache HTTP Client (4.x, the successor to commons http 3.x), on `HttpClient` the method:

```
HttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest request)
```

States in the JavaDocs:

> "Executes a request using the default context."

- What is the default context (referring to an `HttpContext` object)?
- How can I configure the default context so I don't need to pass it on each call to `execute()`?  (I don't control the call to execute(), but I control creating the HttpClient)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default context is configured by the `HttpClient` implementation that you are using.  For implementations based on `AbstractHttpClient`,  the work is done by the `createHttpContext()` method.  Note that a new default context is created for each `execute` call.

One way to configure the default context yourself would be to extend one of the existing `HttpClient` implementation classes and override the method.

Another way is to set the various parameters that the method uses; e.g. the connection manager's scheme registry, the authScheme registry, the cookieSpecs registry, the cookie store or the credentials provider.

For the record, here's what the `DefaultHttpClient.createHttpContext()` does:

```
@Override
protected HttpContext createHttpContext() {
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    context.setAttribute(
        ClientContext.SCHEME_REGISTRY, 
        getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry());
    context.setAttribute(
        ClientContext.AUTHSCHEME_REGISTRY, 
        getAuthSchemes());
    context.setAttribute(
        ClientContext.COOKIESPEC_REGISTRY, 
        getCookieSpecs());
    context.setAttribute(
        ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, 
        getCookieStore());
    context.setAttribute(
        ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, 
        getCredentialsProvider());
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code for [`AbstractHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#272) that creates the default `HttpContext`, you can control the values that it is created with through setting attributes on the `HttpClient` instance, by invoking `setCredentialsProvider(CredentialsProvider credsProvider)` for instance. Is there any particular property(ies) that you are looking to configure?

Comment: I'm trying to default the AUTH_CACHE so that all requests pre-authorize the basic-auth headers (as this is a REST client connecting to known servers only over https):
localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
I didn't see any way to do that without setting my own default context right?

Comment: You are correct, I don't see any other way to do what you need. @Stephen C's suggestion of subclassing an existing `HttpClient` implementation would be the only way with the current API.